# Open Source library for calculating exposures?

Tags: programming, simulations, exposure, library

I would like to know an **open source quantitative library/ies that can calculate exposures out of the box** (I have investigated a bit on OpenGamma/Strata libraries with no luck and the website of QuantLib is down so I saw nothing there as well..)

I imagine that one can use already implemented pricing tools, and do exposure calculation via  e.g. Monte-Carlo simulations, but I am interested in the more general (ready to try) solution with testCases as provided for various functionality for example in OpenGamma library.

Maybe somebody can advise an alternative, **introduction quality book, for calculating exposures and doing value adjustments in some OpenSource libraries?**
This book might cover such questions:

1. **what are the risk factors of a simple swap?** ( if I am correct the risk factors of a simple swap are floating and discounting rates at each of the swap coupons times, i.e. a list of these values). **How do we simulate them (i.e. which models are applied)?**
2. I am also **very curious of the typical calibration process of parameters of the risk factor models**..
3. the book could explain step-by-step on how to compute simple swap exposure

(I am new to this topic, and Jon Gregory book frustrates me because of material covered there is so broad and a huge amount of practical details makes me lost myself yet has no detailed recipe on how to do basic exposure calculation of a swap.)

Thank you a lot. Sorry for a long post.

Comment: Did you already take a look at the Open Source Risk Engine http://www.opensourcerisk.org/documentation/ ? I wouldnt call it out of the box, but it should cover all you need. The documentation is also pretty good and there are a lot of examples to get started.

Comment: @Andrew, this is exactly what I searched for! Thank you. I am currently trying to open it